# Nesting If Statement in Foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to automatically exclude entries in my blog that have negative votes (<0). Below is the code i'm using, but it does not exclude, keeps showing blogs with negative votes. (On a public system now, so might not reply until later, but, Thanks for the help!)

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // get initial query from index

            $table = 'txt';
            $item = 'vt_' .$table.($_GET['id']);

            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$sql = $db->query('SELECT * from txt ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '.$browse);


$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT vote FROM voting where item = ?');
($stmt->execute(array($item)));
($vrow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

            foreach ($sql as $row) {
            if ($vrow['vote'] < 0){
              echo "<b>Update:</b><br>";
              echo "<font color = 'red'><i>", "This Update,", "</i></font>", "<br>";
              echo "By: ", ($row['username']), "<br>"; 
              echo "At: ", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>";
              echo "<font color = 'red'><i>Has been</i> <b>Voted Out</b></font>", "<br>";
              echo "<span class='loginnotreq'>", "<b>", ($row['edited']), "</b>", "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;", "<span 

class='loginreq'>", "<b>", ($row['locked']), "</b>", "</span>", "</span>";
              echo "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;";
              if($row['locked'] !='locked'){
              echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ='edit-post-login.php?pid=".$row['id']."&login=true&edit=true' method='post' id ='form-id' 

data-ajax='false' '><b><span class = 'neutral'>edit post</span></b></a>";}

              echo "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;";


              echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div><br>";              
              }
              else {
              echo "<b>Update:</b><br>";
              echo ($row['message']), "<br>";
              echo "By: ", ($row['username']), "<br>"; 
              echo "At: ", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>";              
              echo "<span class='loginnotreq'>", "<b>", ($row['edited']), "</b>", "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;", "<span 

class='loginreq'>", "<b>", ($row['locked']), "</b>", "</span>", "</span>";
              echo "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;";
              if($row['locked'] !='locked'){
              echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ='edit-post-login.php?pid=".$row['id']."&login=true&edit=true' method='post' id ='form-id' 

data-ajax='false' '><b><span class = 'neutral'>edit post</span></b></a>";}

              echo "&nbsp;", "&nbsp;";


              echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div><br>";
              }

              }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your query to only return rows with votes equal to or more than zero:

For example:

```
SELECT vote FROM voting where item = ? and vote >= 0
```

This way you would not need the conditional in your loop. You would only need the section that deals with votes more than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer (without copying and pasting all of your code):

```
foreach($row as $post) {
  if($post['rating'] >= 0) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the value to **INT**  as when it comes from the DB it is usually in form of **String**:

```
 if ( (int)$vrow['vote'] < 0){ ...
```